# How to run a php function on page reload?

Tags: php

i want to know how to run a function when the user press f5 to reload the page.

Didnt find a thing about it. is it even possible?

Comment: call `ajax` on page load.

Comment: PHP function will be called automatically (if it was called when loaded first time) when you reload the page.

Comment: i think you are looking for window.onbeforeunload()